# How could I reduce the long cold start time when doing SSR from Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, cold-start

I have an SSR server for React.JS app made with CRA, ConnectedRouter, Redux and Saga. I am trying to host this server under AWS Lambda using the below code:

```
const serverlessExpress = require('@vendia/serverless-express');
const app = require('./index');
const binaryMimeTypes = [
  'application/javascript',
  ...
  'text/xml'
];
exports.handler = serverlessExpress({
  app,
  binaryMimeTypes
}).handler;
```

This wrapper pulls the setup code below:

```
const md5File = require('md5-file');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// CSS styles will be imported on load and that complicates matters... ignore those bad boys!
const ignoreStyles = require('ignore-styles');
const register = ignoreStyles.default;

// We also want to ignore all image requests
// When running locally these will load from a standard import
// When running on the server, we want to load via their hashed version in the build folder
const extensions = ['.gif', '.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png', '.svg'];

// Override the default style ignorer, also modifying all image requests
register(ignoreStyles.DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS, (mod, filename) => {
  if (!extensions.find(f => filename.endsWith(f))) {
    // If we find a style
    return ignoreStyles.noOp();
  }
  // for images that less than 10k, CRA will turn it into Base64 string, but here we have to do it again
  const stats = fs.statSync(filename);
  const fileSizeInBytes = stats.size / 1024;
  if (fileSizeInBytes <= 10) {
    mod.exports = `data:image/${mod.filename
      .split('.')
      .pop()};base64,${fs.readFileSync(mod.filename, {
      encoding: 'base64'
    })}`;
    return ignoreStyles.noOp();
  }

  // If we find an image
  const hash = md5File.sync(filename).slice(0, 8);
  const bn = path.basename(filename).replace(/(\.\w{3})$/, `.${hash}$1`);

  mod.exports = `/static/media/${bn}`;
});

// Set up babel to do its thing... env for the latest toys, react-app for CRA
// Notice three plugins: the first two allow us to use import rather than require, the third is for code splitting
// Polyfill is required for Babel 7, polyfill includes a custom regenerator runtime and core-js
require('@babel/polyfill');
require('@babel/register')({
  ignore: [/\/(build|node_modules)\//],
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    'dynamic-import-node',
    'react-loadable/babel'
  ]
});

// Now that the nonsense is over... load up the server entry point
const app = require('./server');
module.exports = app;
```

Then I have the regular express server in my server.js

```
// Express requirements
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import compression from 'compression';
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
import forceDomain from 'forcedomain';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

// Our loader - this basically acts as the entry point for each page load
import loader from './loader';

// Create our express app using the port optionally specified
const main = () => {
  const app = express();
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  // Compress, parse, log, and raid the cookie jar
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
  app.use(cookieParser());

  // Set up homepage, static assets, and capture everything else
  app.use(express.Router().get('/', loader));
  const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
  app.use(favicon(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/icons/favicon.ico')));
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')));
  app.use(loader);

  // We tell React Loadable to load all required assets and start listening - ROCK AND ROLL!
  Loadable.preloadAll().then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`));
  });

  // Handle the bugs somehow
  app.on('error', error => {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
      throw error;
    }

    const bind = typeof PORT === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + PORT : 'Port ' + PORT;

    switch (error.code) {
      case 'EACCES':
        console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
        process.exit(1);
        break;
      case 'EADDRINUSE':
        console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
        process.exit(1);
        break;
      default:
        throw error;
    }
  });

  return app;
};

module.exports = main();
```

Then, I have the loader do:

```
// Express requirements
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

// React requirements
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Frontload, frontloadServerRender } from 'react-frontload';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

// Our store, entrypoint, and manifest
import createStore from '../src/configureStore';
import App from '../src/containers/app';
import manifest from '../build/asset-manifest.json';

// Some optional Redux functions related to user authentication
//import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from '../src/modules/auth';

// LOADER
export default (req, res) => {
  /*
    A simple helper function to prepare the HTML markup. This loads:
      - Page title
      - SEO meta tags
      - Preloaded state (for Redux) depending on the current route
      - Code-split script tags depending on the current route
  */
  const injectHTML = (data, { html, title, meta, body, scripts, state }) => {
    data = data.replace('<html>', `<html ${html}>`);
    data = data.replace(/<title>.*?<\/title>/g, title);
    data = data.replace('</head>', `${meta}</head>`);
    data = data.replace(
      '<div id="root"></div>',
      `<div id="root">${body}</div><script>window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${state}</script>${scripts.join(
        ''
      )}`
    );

    return data;
  };

  // Load in our HTML file from our build
  fs.readFile(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/index.html'),
    'utf8',
    (err, htmlData) => {
      ...
```

The entire process, including transpilation, and the time necessary to start the express server takes quite a while. My latency could be anywhere between 100ms for a warm lambda, all the way to around 3 seconds.

Are there some low-hanging fruit improvements that I could apply to my code?

Answer (score 0):

Cant speak much about the code, but a lot of the lambda performance depends on it's memory preset. There is a tight relationship between the assigned memory to the lambda and it's computing power as per the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/computing-power.html

Thus increasing the memory of your lambda might give it a significant speed boost. I usually strive for `1769` MB as that has proven to be the sweet spot between the price and speed.

You could also look into provisioned concurrency, beware though, using provisioned resources will cause your lambda to always be in a warm state (you will continuously pay for the allocated resources) and also your Lambda invocations will start to get throttled if the amount of requests received by the lambda starts overflowing your provisioned resources.

There is an entire doc section focused entirely on lambda performance optimization, I'm linking it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/perf-optimize.html